# Fetch data from all classes having same name using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new with javascript and the problem I have is that while building a chrome extension I need to extract data from a website let's say "www.abc.com". The data that I need is all present in all divs with the class="className" (say). How can I get the data from that particular class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code into your content script:

```
var request = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            // xhr.responseText contains the raw html of the page
        } else if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // handler the error
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
request("http://abc.com");
```

Once you get the raw html of the page you may use jQuery to fetch the needed divs and their content:

```
var page = $(xhr.responseText);
var divs = page.find(".className");
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
   var data = divs.eq(i).html();
   // do something with the data
}
```

Comment: No, I don't have access to the page's document object. I have to fetch data from "www.abc.com"'s divs having class="className".

Comment: So, you are building an extension for Chrome which needs to make request to external web page and gets that info. Is that the case?

Comment: Yup. I have to fetch data from an external webpage.

Comment: I used the function you provided, replaced the `request("http://abc.com");` by `request("http://www.ebay.com");` and replaced the `className` with `follow-description`, which is a genuine class name on the webpage but the xhr.responseText was empty.